# Meteor: "TypeError: undefined is not an object" when using collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm just trying out Meteor and I'm in general not very advanced in Javascript either. I'm trying to display the text property of an object from a collection on the client side using a template, but I get the error mentioned in the title. I just modified the default Meteor base project a bit.

**main.html:**

```
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    {{> tweet}}
  </section>
</body>

<template name="tweet">
  <h1 class="mt-5">{{text}}</h1>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';

Tweets = new Mongo.Collection('tweets');

Template.tweet.onCreated(function tweetOnCreated() {
  var txt = Tweets.findOne().text;
  this.text = new ReactiveVar(txt);
});

Template.tweet.helpers({
  text() {
    return Template.instance().text.get();
  },
});
```

What is wrong with `var txt = Tweets.findOne().text;`? Am I having a general misunderstanding of Javascript here or is this error somehow related to how Meteor works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to how Meteor works.

When the client starts up, it doesn't have any data yet. The client then opens subscriptions with the server (assuming you still have the default autopublish package installed, this is done for you), which send through the data shortly afterwards.

It's this "shortly afterwards" part that is the issue here.

In your case, this means when `Tweets.findOne()` runs, it doesn't have the data yet and so there is no document to read `text` from. Thus the error. Prevent the error by checking if a document was returned:

```
Template.tweet.onCreated(function () {
  var doc = Tweets.findOne();
  if (doc) {
    this.text = new ReactiveVar(doc.text);
  }
});
```

If you try this out, the error will be gone, but still no text being rendered.

So now we want that section of code to run again when the data is available. Blaze does this automatically in helpers, but everywhere else you need to wrap it in an `autorun`:

```
Template.tweet.onCreated(function () {
  this.text = new ReactiveVar();
  this.autorun(() => {
    var doc = Tweets.findOne();
    if (doc) {
      this.text.set(doc.text);
    }
  });
});
```

I also moved the creation of the reactive var out of the autorun because we only want to create it once and then set or get it's value.

Alternatively, I mentioned earlier that helpers automatically autorun. This means you can find the tweet in the helper to simplify your template a little:

```
Template.tweet.helpers({
  text() {
    var doc = Tweets.findOne();
    if (doc) return doc.text;
  },
});
```

Even better, we don't need the `ReactiveVar` anymore and can delete the whole `onCreated` function!